# logging verbosity mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, logging, verbosity

The default **log error verbosity** is 3 for **mysql 5.7**.  I'm trying to set this to a **level of 2** in the **cnf file** but I'm not sure of the syntax.

Comment: All the options in cnf are basically `param = value`, so you should add `log_error_verbosity = 2`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.  Here's what I have....[mysqld_safe]
datadir=/s01/mysqldata1
log-error= /n01/mysqladmin1/log/mysqld.log
log_error_verbosity = 2
pid-file= /n01/mysqladmin1/mysqld.pid
I restart mysqld and the value is still set to 3

Comment: It seems having this value under mysqld_safe was the issue.  Moved the param and value out and it now takes effect.  thx

Answer (score 12):

> The GLOBAL variable `log_warnings` sets the level for verbosity which
>   varies by server version. The following snippet illustrates:
>
> ```
> SELECT @@log_warnings; -- make a note of your prior setting
> SET GLOBAL log_warnings=2; -- setting above 1 increases output (see server version)
> ```
>
> log_warnings as seen above is a dynamic variable.
>
> Configuration file changes in cnf and ini files might look like the
>   following.
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> log_error        = /path/to/CurrentError.log
> log_warnings     = 2
> ```
>
> Please see the MySQL Manual Page entitled [The Error Log][] especially
>   for Flushing and Renaming the Error Log file, and [Error Log
>   Verbosity] with versions related to log_warnings. The GLOBAL variable
>   `log_warnings` sets the level for verbosity which varies by server
>   version. The following snippet illustrates:
>
> ```
> SELECT @@log_warnings; -- make a note of your prior setting
> SET GLOBAL log_warnings=2; -- setting above 1 increases output (see server version)
> ```
>
> `log_warnings` as seen above is a dynamic variable.
>
> Configuration file changes in `cnf` and `ini` files might look like
>   the following.
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> log_error        = /path/to/CurrentError.log
> log_warnings     = 2
> ```
>
> Please see the MySQL Manual Page entitled [The Error Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html)
>   especially for Flushing and Renaming the Error Log file, and Error Log
>   Verbosity with versions related to `log_warnings`.

MySQL 5.7.2 expanded the warning level verbosity to 3 and added the GLOBAL `log_error_verbosity`. Again, it was [introduced](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_verbosity) in 5.7.2. It can be set dynamically and checked as a variable or set via `cnf` or `ini` configuration file settings.

As of MySQL 5.7.2:

```
[mysqld]
log_error           = /path/to/CurrentError.log
log_warnings        = 2
log_error_verbosity = 3
```

Change yours to 2 if you want, above.

You can dynamically set, and check, respectively, with:

```
SET GLOBAL log_error_verbosity=2; -- set it
SELECT @@log_error_verbosity=2; -- sanity check, view it
```

yet this will be reset to `cnf` or `ini` file settings upon server restart.

[image]

I will try to improve our Docs page on that.

How to set the Configuration file (`cnf` or `ini`, Linux or Windows, respectively).

The my.cnf and my.ini files reside in the `basedir`. If they do not exist, you can create them, else they will use defaults baked into the server. Often there is a stubbed out file in `basedir`, not active, named `my-default`, as a template. Use that to create the real my.cnf or my.ini. Issue a

```
SELECT @@basedir;
```

to find the location where `my.ini` (Windows) or `my.cnf` (Linux) should reside. Note, you will need to have sufficient rights to modify these files. In Windows, for instance, I need to run Notepad as Administrator to write such a file.

The following are a few commands issued to confirm a change to `my.ini` (for Windows, `my.cnf` for Linux) having set `log_error_verbosity` to 2. Note this is *after* a server restart which would have used those `ini` or `cnf` changes:

[image]

I show the use of `basedir` because that is where your `ini` or `cnf` file must exist depending on your operating system.