# Cannot set mysql root password after a fresh installation

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL 5.7.26 on Ubuntu 18.04, but cannot login or reset 'root' user password. I tried all the ways from [the two top answers to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991228/what-is-the-default-root-pasword-for-mysql-5-7), but with no success.

1. There is no `/var/log/mysqld.log` file on my machine so I cannot find the temporary password.
2. Changing the root password with `mysql_secure_installation` does not work.
3. `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` exist immediately.
4. Tried setting the root password with `mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p`, but after I logout and then login back there is still `auth_socket` in `MySQL.user` table (for some reason `UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';` does not take an effect), even if I do `flush privileges` and `commit`.

**EDIT1:**

Also tried [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) but

```
sudo su - mysql
mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```

exits immediately and in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` I have this:

```
2019-06-12T14:16:16.870292Z 0 [ERROR] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.
2019-06-12T14:16:16.870295Z 0 [ERROR] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
2019-06-12T14:16:16.870298Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

directory `/var/run/mysqld/` does not exist, but it is created if I do `sudo service mysql start` and deleted with I do `sudo service mysql stop`

The same situation with `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`:

```
Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

**EDIT2:**

Tried on a clean Ubuntu 18.04 installation with the same result and did not find anything with

```
sudo grep -r 'temporary password' / --include=*.log
```

I also tried to create the directory as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954455/mysql-daemon-lock-issue) (with 'mysql' owner), but got 'permission denied' in logs, with file 'mysql-init' (also with 'mysql' owner').

Comment: did you try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html?

Comment: @Ntwobike yes, see EDIT1, probably something is wrong with unix socket.

Comment: I think it is a permissions error, though I haven't messed with mysql in several years. 
 See if the mysql user has access to create `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock`.

Comment: #3 it's supposed to; that launches the daemon - you then go in (you won't be made to login) and use the normal password setting facilities - then shut down the daemon and relaunch it normally

Comment: @PaulJ 'mysql' user is the owner of this file if MySQL is started normally. see also EDIT2

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky 1. You can also increase your log verbosity to possibly get a better idea of what's going on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992813/logging-verbosity-mysql-5-7 // 2. I'd try to experiment doing: `sudo chown mysql.mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock && sudo chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock`  then restarting it, definitely NOT how you would want to do it in production.  // 3. The only other guess I can make is mysql is already running, though I'm REALLY grasping for straws with that, `ps aux | grep mysql`.

Comment: @PaulJ 2. socket files are removed with the service is stopped. 3. As far as I see, mysql_secure_installation requires mysqld to be running.