# Microk8s Ingress returns 502

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I'm new at Kubernetes and trying to do a simple project to connect MySQL and PhpMyAdmin using Kubernetes on my Ubuntu 20.04. I created the components needed and here is the components.

mysql.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: mysql-root-password
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: mysql-user-username
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: mysql-user-password
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-configmap
                  key: mysql-database
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```

phpmyadmin.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin
  labels:
    app: phpmyadmin
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: phpmyadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phpmyadmin
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: phpmyadmin
        image: phpmyadmin
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: PMA_HOST
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mysql-configmap
              key: database_url
        - name: PMA_PORT
          value: "3306"
        - name: PMA_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: mysql-user-username
        - name: PMA_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: mysql-user-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: phpmyadmin
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 3000
```

ingress-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: phpmyadmin-service
      port:
        number: 8080
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: phpmyadmin-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

when I execute `microk8s kubectl get ingress ingress-service`, the output is:

```
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS      ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress-service   public   test.com   127.0.0.1   80      45s
```

and when I tried to access test.com, that's when I got 502 error.

My kubectl version:

```
Client Version: v1.22.2-3+9ad9ee77396805
Server Version: v1.22.2-3+9ad9ee77396805
```

My microk8s' client and server version:

```
Client:
  Version:  v1.5.2
  Revision: 36cc874494a56a253cd181a1a685b44b58a2e34a
  Go version: go1.15.15

Server:
  Version:  v1.5.2
  Revision: 36cc874494a56a253cd181a1a685b44b58a2e34a
  UUID: b2bf55ad-6942-4824-99c8-c56e1dee5949
```

As for my microk8s' own version, I followed the installation instructions from [here](https://microk8s.io/docs), so it should be `1.21/stable`. (Couldn't find the way to check the exact version from the internet, if someone know how, please tell me how)

`mysql.yaml` logs:

```
2021-10-14 07:05:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
2021-10-14 07:05:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-10-14 07:05:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
2021-10-14 07:05:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2021-10-14T07:05:38.960693Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) initializing of server in progress as process 41
2021-10-14T07:05:38.967970Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-10-14T07:05:39.531763Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-10-14T07:05:40.591862Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-10-14T07:05:40.592247Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-10-14T07:05:40.670594Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2021-10-14 07:05:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2021-10-14 07:05:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2021-10-14T07:05:45.362827Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 90
2021-10-14T07:05:45.486702Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-10-14T07:05:45.845971Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-10-14T07:05:46.022043Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-10-14T07:05:46.022189Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-10-14T07:05:46.023446Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-10-14T07:05:46.023728Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-10-14T07:05:46.026088Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-10-14T07:05:46.044967Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-10-14T07:05:46.045036Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-10-14 07:05:46+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2021-10-14 07:05:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database testing-database
2021-10-14 07:05:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user testinguser
2021-10-14 07:05:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user testinguser access to schema testing-database

2021-10-14 07:05:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2021-10-14T07:05:48.422053Z 13 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.26).
2021-10-14T07:05:50.543822Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2021-10-14 07:05:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2021-10-14 07:05:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2021-10-14T07:05:51.711889Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 1
2021-10-14T07:05:51.725302Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-10-14T07:05:51.959356Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-10-14T07:05:52.162432Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-10-14T07:05:52.162568Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-10-14T07:05:52.163400Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-10-14T07:05:52.163556Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-10-14T07:05:52.165840Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-10-14T07:05:52.181516Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-10-14T07:05:52.181562Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

`phpmyadmin.yaml` logs:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.1.114.139. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.1.114.139. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Oct 14 03:57:32.653011 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Debian) PHP/7.4.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 14 03:57:32.653240 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Here is also my `Allocatable` on `describe nodes` command:

```
Allocatable:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  113289380Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             5904508Ki
  pods:               110
```

and the `Allocated resources`:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                550m (13%)  200m (5%)
  memory             270Mi (4%)  370Mi (6%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you, please, provide your logs?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, check the latest update @kkopczak

Comment: Sorry for long time for response. It looks like you are lack of resources. I found [this similar issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/3). Could you run `kubectl describe nodes` command and check available resources?

Comment: Could you please specify what part of the returns of `kubectl describe nodes` that you want to see? @kkopczak

Comment: `Allocated resources:` and `Allocatable:`

Comment: Done, check the updated question @kkopczak

Comment: Which version of Microk8s did you use and is it from stable [channel](https://microk8s.io/docs/setting-snap-channel) or different one? Could you set [`log_error_verbosity`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#:~:text=The%20Error%20Log%E2%80%9D.-,log_error_verbosity,-Command-Line%20Format) to [the highest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992813/logging-verbosity-mysql-5-7) )?

Comment: I've added microk8s' client, server, and own version. As for the log error verbosity, I did not see the env variables on the mysql's docker image to set that, so I don't think I can. And when I tried to printout the `@@log_warning`, it threw an error saying `Unknown system variable 'log_warnings'` @kkopczak

Comment: What about this 502, how exactly is the answer, does it have any body? I also don't understand why is there a rewrite target. What happens if you remove it from the ingress?

Comment: The ingress service just gets normally created, but when I visit `test.com`, same thing, 502. @AndD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a fudged up mistake of mine, where I specify the phpmyadmin's container port to be 3000, while the default image port opens at 80. After changing the `containerPort` and `phpmyadmin-service`'s `targetPort` to 80, it opens the phpmyadmin's page.

So sorry for kkopczak and AndD for the fuss and also big thanks for trying to help! :)